# Apache2 Installation on Xbuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, apache-httpd, webserver, xubuntu

I'm moderately new to linux.I've been using it for now around 1 year. Now I'm on xubuntu. before that, I used Linux Mint, Debian, Ubuntu.
Guys, I need to set up apache for testing web forums with perl for now. I know how to install web server. I installed using `sudo apt-get install apache2`.
I like to tweak with web server so I followed a tutorial on a web site called [linuxhint](https://linuxhint.com/install_apache_web_server_ubuntu.)

Most instructions work but there was one that wouldn't work. He edited a file called **ServerName** but I couldn't find it in my settings. I uninstalled apache after that.
Can someone tell me where tutorial went wrong and how to solve that ?
Do recommend a good beginners book to read. I find online documentation very difficult to understand.

Thax in advance.

Comment: You need to create the `servername.conf` by yourself. See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#1-overview

Comment: I supposed it must be created inside /var/www directory. rIght? Is there any particular directive to include inside it ? @GAD3R

Comment: @GAD3R I did the steps to the latter though I got an error. Website didn't load after all the steps. can you check the link please ? I did it many times. can't figure out where is the wrong